# Swifts didSelectRow not inserting Selected Pickerview Item in UITextfield

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Im not having any luck with getting my textField populated with the selected item from my UIPickerview. The rows in the Pickerview show up perfectly but on selecting an item i am not able to get that value to save into my uitextfield.

[image]

Code:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent
    component: Int, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    switch pDisplay
    {
    case .preparedby:
        var u:SWUsers = arrPeople[row]
        textField1.text = "\(u.fullName)"
        println(u.fullName)
    case .status:
        textField2.text = txt2Array[row]
    case .contractor:
        var c:SWGContractors = arrContr[row]
        textField10.text = c.name
        println(c.name)
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

The data is pulling from a NSManageObject class in my coredata model. The array loads perfect, i just need to get the value of the selected row. Any ideas would be appreciated.

update:

I set breakpoints and it looks like it stops executing after:

```
  func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    //return arrNo.count

    switch pDisplay {
    case .preparedby:
        return arrPeople.count
    case .status:
        return txt2Array.count
    case .contractor:
        return arrContr.count
    default:
        return 0
    }
} <--- stops here
```

Comment: Have you checked by putting the breakpoints, that your are going in the right case ??

Comment: yes I have. it gets through to the case and crashes...

Comment: Will you put a comment in your code, where your app get crashed.Also check whether you are getting any nil values or not.

Comment: just added a comment... looks like its stopping after it gets the count and presents the popup. Doesn't even make it into didSelectRow... any ideas?

Comment: what are you getting in `pDisplay` ??

Comment: its an enumerator that skips through my switch/case statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88613/discussion-between-rajatp-and-mizakita).